# How to export all external activities from Eloqua using Bulk API

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

We need to export all external activities from our Eloqua instance. We have been able to export the "normal" activities using the activities endpoint (Bulk/2.0/activities) where it is required to specify the activity type. I searched on the documentation to see if there was a exclusive endpoint for that and didn't find any. Also, I created an activity export definition and tried to filter by "filter":"'{{Activity.Type}}' = 'ExternalActivities' and I got an error indicating "Unknown {{Activity.Type}} filter. Valid options are EmailSend, EmailOpen, EmailClickthrough, Subscribe, Unsubscribe, Bounceback, FormSubmit, PageView, WebVisit". So, how can I export external activities using Bulk API?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?